# Coping files from Azure blob storage to azure data lake store

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I am Coping files from Azure blob storage to azure data lake store, I need to pick files from year(folder)\month(folder)\day(txt files are on day bases).I am able to do one file with hadrcoded path but i am not able to pick file per day and process to copy in azure data lake store. Can anyone please help me.

I am using ADF V2 and using UI designer to create my connections,datasets and pipeline my steps are which i is working fine

- copy file from blob storage to data lake store
- picking that file from data lake store and processing through usql for transform data.
- that transform data i am saving in Azure SQL DB

Please give me answer i am not able to get any help b/c all help is in JSON i am looking how i will define and pass parameters in UI designer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the partitioned file path part, you could take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936847/azure-datafactory-incremental-blob-copy). 
You could use copy data tool to handle it.

Comment: but then my usql need to pick these files from azure data lake store dynamically as well, how usql will pick these files from year, month foders by day one by one?

Comment: You could pass parameters to your USQL script.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-data-lake-analytics#dynamic-parameters There is a sample in this doc. Hope it could help

Comment: i am not able to see year, month and day option in ADF V2 the link you sent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936847/azure-datafactory-incremental-blob-copy

Comment: I can see option, once i change dataset with parameters that reflects on pipeline source. thanks it worked.